# Blending issues between InstancedMesh using a ShaderMaterial (trying to reproduce mix-blend-mode: overlay from Figma)

Tags: three.js, glsl, blending

I've been working on blending between InstancedMesh using a ShaderMaterial. The blending between the InstancedMesh works fine with THREE.JS blending mode (Additive, Substractive, ...) but i struggle to match the Figma design with thoses (See the attached screenshots, first is the current result with THREE.JS using Additive blend mode, second is the result i need from Figma).

[Current Result using Additive Blending](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZ6d8.png)

[Result needed from Figma](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qmdzl.png)

A mix-blend-mode: overlay is used on Figma between all the circles (the InstancedMesh in Three.js), so i tried to add some glsl blend overlay code (https://github.com/jamieowen/glsl-blend) like that in the ShaderMaterial used by the InstancedMesh :

```
uniform vec3 uColors[6];
uniform float uThresholds[6];

varying vec2 vUv;

float blendOverlay(float base, float blend) {
  return base<0.5?(2.0*base*blend):(1.0-2.0*(1.0-base)*(1.0-blend));
}

vec3 blendOverlay(vec3 base, vec3 blend) {
  return vec3(blendOverlay(base.r,blend.r),blendOverlay(base.g,blend.g),blendOverlay(base.b,blend.b));
}

vec3 blendOverlay(vec3 base, vec3 blend, float opacity) {
  return (blendOverlay(base, blend) * opacity + base * (1.0 - opacity));
}

void main() {
  vec3 color = mix(uColors[0], uColors[1], smoothstep(uThresholds[0], uThresholds[1], vUv.y));

  color = mix(color, uColors[2], smoothstep(uThresholds[1], uThresholds[2], vUv.y));
  color = mix(color, uColors[3], smoothstep(uThresholds[2], uThresholds[3], vUv.y));
  color = mix(color, uColors[4], smoothstep(uThresholds[3], uThresholds[4], vUv.y));
  color = mix(color, uColors[5], smoothstep(uThresholds[4], uThresholds[5], vUv.y));

  gl_FragColor = vec4(blendOverlay(color.rgb, ???), 1.0);
}
```

I understood that i would need some sampler2D uniforms to use them as texture2D for the blendOverlay method to work, but my problem is how can i render those textures ?
If the overlay was just between a "background" and all the InstancedMesh i could render the InstancedMesh in a renderTarget once and use it as a texture. But here i need the overlay blending to be between all the InstancedMesh objects. Should i render the InstancedMesh one by one in a renderTarget and store every textures ? I'm a bit lost here hehe.